# Group action on monoid with involution - Laws relating involution of element (from monoid) with inverse function (from group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, monoid, involutions

### Preliminaries

(Remarks on notation: To denote function application, I will use the [Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553139/operator-and-function-precedence-in-haskell#23553985) notation $f\ x$, rather than the traditional mathematical notation $f (x)$. The expression $x^-$ denotes an involutive operation on $x$. By an intentional [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), $f^-$ denotes the inverse function of $f$.)

Let's start with the standard definition of a [monoid with involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_with_involution):

$$M=\langle S, \cdot, \bot, ^-\rangle$$
Laws:
$$x\cdot(y\cdot z) = (x\cdot y)\cdot z = x\cdot y\cdot z\\
x\cdot\bot = \bot\cdot x = x\\
(x^-)^- = x\\
(x\cdot y)^- = y^-\cdot x^-$$

Let's also have this [permutation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group) (where all functions in $F$ have signature $S\longrightarrow S$):
$$G=\langle F, \circ,\ ^-, i\rangle$$
Laws:
$$f\circ (g\circ h) = (f\circ g)\circ h = f\circ g\circ h\\
f\circ i = i\circ f = f\\
f\circ f^- = f^-\circ f = i\\
(f^-)^- = f$$

Finally, let's also have a [left group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) of $G$ on $S$ (the carrier set of $M$),

$$\leftarrow\ :\ ~F\times S\ \mapsto\ S$$
Laws:
$$i\leftarrow x = x\\
f\leftarrow(g\leftarrow x) = (f\circ g)\leftarrow x$$

### Conjectures

$$(f\ x^-)^- = f^-\ x\\
(f\leftarrow x^-)^- = f^-\leftarrow x\\
^-\ \circ\ f\ \circ\ ^- = f^-$$

(where all left-hand occurrences of $^-$ refer to the involution operation on $S$, and all right-hand occurrences of $^-$ refer to the inversion operation on $F$.)

Question: **How can you prove them?**

---

### Motivating scenario where these conjectures work

$S$ = a set of lists of symbols

$\cdot$ = list concatenation (`++` in Haskell)

$\bot$ = empty list (`[]` in Haskell)

$^-$ = operation that inverts a list (`reverse` in Haskell)

$\circ$ = function composition (`.` in Haskell)

$\leftarrow$ = function application (`$` in Haskell)

$i$ = identity function (`id` in Haskell)

Beyond the identity function, $F$ includes the two functions `rotateRight` and `rotateLeft`, defined as follows in the Haskell programming language (the source code is self-explanatory, but if you prefer to see it in action, copy and paste it to [Replit](https://replit.com/languages/haskell)):

```
--Moves the initial element (if it exists) to the final position of the list
rotateRight [] = []
rotateRight (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
--Moves the final element (if it exists) to the initial position of the list
rotateLeft = reverse . rotateRight . reverse
--An example input
main = print $ rotateLeft [2,3,5,7]
--Output: [7,2,3,5]
```

Thus, our group $G$ has a single [generating element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group), `rotateRight`. And `rotateLeft` is the inverse of `rotateRight`.

By looking at the definition of `rotateLeft`, it is clear that the 3 conjectures succeed in this particular scenario:

```
reverse (rotateRight (reverse x)) == rotateLeft x
reverse (rotateRight $ reverse x) == (rotateLeft $ x)
reverse . rotateRight . reverse == rotateLeft
```

If we chose an example list, each of the conjectures can be executed by replacing it for `rotateLeft [2,3,5,7]` in the previous source code, as follows:

```
reverse (rotateRight (reverse [2,3,5,7])) == rotateLeft [2,3,5,7]
reverse (rotateRight $ reverse [2,3,5,7]) == (rotateLeft $ [2,3,5,7])
(reverse . rotateRight . reverse) [2,3,5,7] == rotateLeft [2,3,5,7]
```

Comment: I may be missing something here, but your axioms do not appear to imply any connection between the action of the group $G$ on the set $S$ and the monoid structure $M$ on $S$, so I cannot see any reason to expect your conjectures to be true in general. For example, if $M$ is a commutative monoid with $x^-=x$ for all $x$, then your first conjecture seems to say that $f x = f^- x$ for all $f$ and $x$.

Comment: @derek-holt Thanks for your comment and effort. I'd like to accept your comment as the definitive answer to this question. To be clearer, could you generously provide in an answer, as a counterexample, the Cayley table of a finite monoid where $x=x^-$ for all x and coin up two mutually inverse functions that would break the conjecture $^-\ \circ\ f\ \circ\ ^- = f^-$?